# JIRA: Rest API Authentication for CURL command

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm looking to make a POST request to create an issue on my JIRA server. I was able to make a successful request using postman and basic authentication, but I would like to use the bearer  method.

Here is my curl command:

```
curl --request POST--header 'Authorization: Bearer <token>'--header 'Accept: application/json'--header 'Content-Type: application/json'--data '{ "fields": { "project": {"key": "key"}, "summary": "Bug notification", "description": "THis is a test notification from cmd", "issuetype": {"name": "Bug"},"components": [{ "id": "0000"}], "priority": { "id": "2"}}}'--url 'https://server.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue'
```

Can someone please guide me on how to get the token, I have combed through a lot of documentation and nothing seemed to fit the bill?

Answer (score 0):

you need to go to the [api tokens page](https://id.atlassian.com/manage/api-tokens) and create one from there

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a token by following this instruction https://support.atlassian.com/atlassian-account/docs/manage-api-tokens-for-your-atlassian-account/

After the token is generated, you need to copy it and put some syntax below.

Get the issue example.

```
curl --request GET \
--url 'https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}' \
--user 'email@example.com:<api_token>' \
--header 'Accept: application/json'
```